# SQL select rows which are identical in two values in a way that retains Edit features in output

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies if the answer is dead obvious but in spite of a lot of research and trying out different commands, the solution escapes me (I'm more of a lexicographer than a dev).

We have a table which for various reasons has ended up with some rows which have duplicated values in critical cells. A mockup looks like this:

```
Unique_ID   | E_ID   | Date       | User_ID    | V_value
1           | 500    | 2012-05-12 | 23         | 3
2           | 501    | 2012-05-12 | 23         | 3
3           | 501    | 2012-05-13 | 23         | 1
4           | 502    | 2012-05-13 | 23         | 2
5           | 503    | 2012-05-12 | 23         | 2
6           | 7721   | 2012-05-22 | 8845       | 3
7           | 7722   | 2012-05-22 | 8845       | 3
8           | 7722   | 2012-05-22 | 8845       | 3
9           | 7723   | 2012-05-22 | 8845       | 3
```

So the rows I need as output are Unique_ID 2 & 3 and 7 & 8 as they are identical as regards the E_ID and User_ID field. The values of the other fields are not relevant to our problem. So what I want is this, ideally:

```
Unique_ID   | E_ID   | Date       | User_ID    | V_value
2           | 501    | 2012-05-12 | 23         | 3
3           | 501    | 2012-05-13 | 23         | 1
7           | 7722   | 2012-05-22 | 8845       | 3
8           | 7722   | 2012-05-22 | 8845       | 3
```

For reasons to do with the data, I need the output to appear with the Edit features (in particular the tick-box or at least the Delete feature) because I need to go through the table manually and discard one or the other duplicate based on decisions/conditions that can't be determined with SQL commands.

The closest I have come is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT E_ID, User_ID, COUNT(Unique_ID)
AS V_Count
FROM TableName
GROUP BY E_ID, User_ID
ORDER BY E_ID )
AS X
WHERE V_Count > 1
ORDER BY User_ID ASC, E_ID ASC
```

which does give me the rows with the duplications but because I'm creating the V_Count column to give me the duplicates:

```
E_ID   | User_ID    | V_Count
501    | 23         | 2
7722   | 8845       | 2
```

the output does not give me the Delete option I need - it says it's because there is no unique ID and I get that, as it puts them together in the same row. Is there a way to do this without losing the Unique_ID so I don't lose the Delete function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation to check for a given user_id and e_id if there are more than one rows. Then join it with your table to get all the columns in the result.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (
    select e_id,
        user_id
    from tablename
    group by e_id,
        user_id
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t2
    on t1.e_id = t2.e_id
        and t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Which can be more cleanly expressed using the `USING` clause as:

```
select *
from tablename t1
join (
    select e_id,
        user_id
    from tablename
    group by e_id,
        user_id
    having count(*) > 1
    ) t2 using (e_id, user_id)
```

Comment: Ooooh perfect! Many thanks GurV! I tried Gordon's suggestion too (which works but it seems to take a very long time to run) but this one pops the right rows out straight away!!

Comment: @Akerbeltz - Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

A sort-of simple method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where exists (select 1
              from tablename t2
              where t2.e_id = t.e_id and t2.date = t.date and
                    t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.v_value = t.v_value and
                    t2.unique_id <> t.unique_id
             );
```

An alternative way that puts each combination on a single row with all the ids is:

```
select e_id, date, user_id, v_value,
       group_concat(unique_id) as unique_ids
from tablename t
group by e_id, date, user_id, v_value
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Just a little additional feedback (in case someone else has the same problem) - this one works on a smallish table but it seems to be very hard on the buffer on big tables, we manage to crash MySQL with this one (on a table with ~330k rows). Seems that _join_ is a more efficient way.

Comment: @Akerbeltz . . . An aggregation query should work on 330k rows.  It might take a few seconds, but it should not be causing your server to crash.